# Number of solutions in given equation without use of graphing software

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have been asked to find the number of solutions to the given equation
$$\frac {1}{(x-3)^3} -2x - \cos x = 0$$

Forgive my formatting as I'm new here. I can't seem to find a way to approach this problem. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to the website Math.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the first derivative,

$$-\frac3{(x-3)^4}-2+\sin x$$ we have that the first two terms are below $-2$, while the sine never exceeds $1$. So the function is monotonous decreasing.

But the term $\dfrac1{(x-3)^3}$ forms a vertical asymptote, while $f(-\infty)>0$ and $f(\infty)<0$. Hence there are two roots, on either sides of $x=3$.

Rough sketch (sine oscillations omitted):

[image]

True plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: @Shakti: always think of function variation study.